# How does a java program obtain inputstream after being created on a command line

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to write a Java program where Program1 will create Program2 by calling "java -jar Program2.jar" on command line and write bytes of data using outputstream of process.

The program2 after starting to run after command line call should be able to read data written by program1.

How can the program2 find the input stream of the pipe on which program1 has written data.
Any examples to obtain process instance could be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Maybe start program2 with an argument, giving him a pipe or a temp file?

Comment: I am trying to do this using runtime only providing jar in classpath, so that the class invoking the functionality need not be aware about the class name and package details.

Answer (score 1):

Read from [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) of the second program.

See the Java Tutorial on [I/O from the Command Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("java -jar Program2.jar");
```

Using process you can obtain Input or Output stream.

```
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();
```

Comment: Yes i have done this, but to read the data written by program1 , the class program2 should obtain a instance of input stream, so that data written by program1 can be read. Can you guide me on how to read data in program2

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible as far as I know. But the original invoking program can write the command line parameters to be sent to the second program.

"java -jar Program2.jar param1 param2"

And that's about it....

Comment: You've never heard of pipes then?

Comment: @EJP Are you referring to Java Pipe class and related functionality??

Comment: No, I am referring to the command line syntax whereby you can pipe the output of one command to the input of another, e.g. `echo "fred" | cat`. You shouldn't be posting answers on topics you don't know anything about.

Comment: I actually didn't think that they will be of use since program1 will be invoking program2 not that program1 and program2 will both be run from the command line directly. On the contrary I think I should post answers that I think are right. If I'm wrong someone like you will correct me... Anyway can you post an answer so I can delete this?